# @Query does not give desired result when native query is used

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

iam using spring data jpa in my project

```
package com.mf.acrs.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@Entity(name= "mv_garage_asset_mapping")
public class GarageAssetMapping implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2535545189473989744L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="GARAGE_CODE")
    private String garageCode;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_NAME")
    private String garageName;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_ADDRESS")
    private String garageAddress;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_BRANCH")
    private String garageBranch;

    @Column(name="CONTRACT_NUMBER")
    private String contractNumber;
}
```

this is my entity object

```
package com.mf.acrs.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import com.mf.acrs.model.GarageAssetMapping;

public interface GarageAssetMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<GarageAssetMapping, String> {

//  @Query(name="select u.CONTRACT_NUMBER from mv_garage_asset_mapping u where u.GARAGE_CODE = ?1", nativeQuery = true) //**QUERY 1**

    @Query("select u.contractNumber from mv_garage_asset_mapping u where u.garageCode = ?1") // **QUERY 2**
    List<String> findByGarageCode(String garageCode);
}
```

this is my repository interface

when i use the QUERY 1 in my application the query fired by spring data jpa is

*Hibernate: select garageasse0_.garage_code as garage_code1_2_, garageasse0_.contract_number as contract_number2_2_, garageasse0_.garage_address as garage_address3_2_, garageasse0_.garage_branch as garage_branch4_2_, garageasse0_.garage_name as garage_name5_2_ from mv_garage_asset_mapping garageasse0_ where garageasse0_.garage_code=?*

but when i use QUERY 2 the query fired is

*Hibernate: select garageasse0_.contract_number as col_0_0_ from mv_garage_asset_mapping garageasse0_ where garageasse0_.garage_code=?*

QUERY 2 gives me desired result.
but my question is why spring data jpa fires a incorrect query in 1st case.
in QUERY 1 hibernate tries to pull all the data fields despite the fact i have explicitly written in query that i want to fetch only one field.

What mistake iam doing in this case?

The method defined in the controller which calls the method is below:

```
@PostMapping("/searchAssetsAjax")
    @ResponseBody
    public String searchAssetsAjax(@RequestBody SearchAssetData searchAssetData) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("iam in the searchAssetsAjax "+searchAssetData);
        System.out.println("iam in the searchAssetsAjax "+searchAssetData.toString());
//      System.out.println("throwing exceptions" ); throw new IOException();
        System.out.println("hitting the db "+searchAssetData.getGarageCode());
//      List<String> contractNums = garageAssetMapRepository.findContractNumberByGarageCode(searchAssetData.getGarageCode());

        List<String> contractNums = garageAssetMapRepository.findByGarageCode(searchAssetData.getGarageCode());
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@contract num size is "+contractNums.size());

        for(String contract: contractNums) {
            System.out.println("contract nums are "+contract);
        }
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Did you use the same method signature to when using query 1?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: I can't believe that Spring Data is creating this statement. Can you show the code where you call findByGarageCode

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  i have edited the code to show you the calling portion of code....

Comment: I'm sorry to ask. And you tried query 1 again with that code? Can you post all SQL statements you see? And please just to test name the method findX not findByGarageCode to make sure that it fails if Spring Data is trying to generate the query